# print out nth string using Queue

Tags: java, queue

I want to print out the nth string using the 
Queue data type.

Ex.

```
$ java NthString 5
a b c d e f
< ctrl -d >
```

should give me:

```
b (the fifth string from the right)
```

This is what I have so far, but I do not know my next step:

```
public class NthString {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();

      while(!StdIn.isEmpty()){
         q.enqueue(StdIn.readInt());
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i did not include the part where I imported the libaries. it is neither sun.misc.queue nor java.util.Queue, but edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Queue, from a princeton course i am taking

Comment: Does the library that you are using have documentation? Have you read it?

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by String first, it sounds like you are using it as space separated text? Usually in this context the string would be "a b c d e f", not "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f".  Also, is it permissible to read the entire string/s into memory or you need to process incrementally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class NthString {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Integer n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
      while(!StdIn.isEmpty()){
         q.enqueue(StdIn.readInt());
      }
      while(q.size() > n){
         q.dequeue();
      }
      StdOut.println(q.peek().toString());
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know how these stuff work, so read my comments carefully. I have written a sample for you but it is not exactly what you need but with small changes you can reach the requirement.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class NthString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // java NthString 5
       // when you run this command 5 will come from args as first parameter
       int nth = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

       // Since we get alfabetic from console input your queue must be type of String
       Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();

       // This is in place of your StdIn
       BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

       try {
           String s = "";
           // '/' this is the exit String that is expected from user to give at last to stop reading furthermore
           // in your case it is different, ctrl -d ?
           while (!"/".equals((s = bufferRead.readLine()))) {
               q.add(s);
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       String polled = "";
       int count = 1;

       // now you have to poll from queue back and count to get the nth string
       // since the queue is implemented as linkedlist in my case 5th element will output e instead of b
       while ((polled = q.poll()) != null) {
           if (count == nth) {
               System.out.println(nth + " th string is " + polled);
           }
           count++;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I cant use BufferedReader, IOExceptiom etc, Just Queue, StdIn, and StdOUt. As for the Queue data structure, I have read about it, and of course I have ideas on how to approach the problem, but I feel that they are incorrect, http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/Queue.java.html

Comment: Yes I know that thats why I told you that you have to make small changes, you can not directly use my code, and I can not write it with dependencies that you are using since I do not have them.

Comment: for example, for the problem above, I could dequeue the first s.length - 5 chars, then use peek() to return the first string in the queue, this would in fact give the 5th from the right element, but the problem is i do not know how to dequeue the first whatever elements